# Objective-C - Adding sound on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-audio

I'm making a sound for the iPhone and I'm interested in adding background music and background sounds.

Is CoreAudio right for the job?

And if so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just playing background music and doesn't need advanced controls, try [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html).

For sound effects, use [`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesPlaySystemSound).

Comment: Can't I use AVAudioPlayer for both? For sound effects I meant some I made myself, lol.

Comment: @Johannes: Of course you can use AVAudioPlayer for both, but it seems too heavy weight.